# A recursive puzzle c++ code

Tags: recursion, recursive-algorithms

A recursive puzzle

You have been given a puzzle consisting of a row of squares each containing an integer, like this:

The circle on the initial square is a marker that can move to other squares along the row. At each step in the puzzle, you may move the marker the number of squares indicated by the integer in the square it currently occupies. The marker may move either left or right along the row but may not move past either end. For example, the only legal first move is to move the marker three squares to the right because there is no room to move three spaces to the left. The goal of the puzzle is to move the marker to the 0 at the far end of the row. In this configuration, you can solve the puzzle by making the following set of moves:

[image]

```
void SolvePuzzle(int start, int squares[]){
    if(squares[start]==0)
      return;
    else{
      cout<<squares[start]<<" ";
      if(squares[start]%2==0)
      return SolvePuzzle( start+squares[start],squares);
    else
      return SolvePuzzle( start-squares[start],squares);
    }
}

int main(){
    int arraytest[] = { 3, 6, 4, 1, 3, 4, 2, 5, 3, 0 };
SolvePuzzle(arraytest[0],arraytest);

    return 0;
}
```

I solved this but I need to correct the mistakes in if-statement

Comment: Your condition must express that the + or - move is allowed, i.e. leads to a legal position.

Comment: @YvesDaoust   can you write this condition

Comment: This is elementary, spend some effort.

Comment: Any one can help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Express in words what the condition should be, referring to your variables.

Comment: I think this is not the right place for posting such programming questions. Maybe you should post it on http://stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 1):

You wrote that if the number is even it goes right, whereas you should check if its smaller than size and positive.
Then the program shall test both possibilities.
There lacks a condition maybe there are several possibilities you probably have to choose the shortest.

You should also add a flag to know if you were already there to avoid loops.

Comment: You absolutely have to worry about the length of the solution, as there can be infinite loops. So even with the right condition, the OP's solution could fail.